# ls -lh and du -h giving different file sizes when truncate is used

Tags: files, ls, disk-usage

I am trying to find out a way to reduce the size of a log file while it is being used.

So for a file I tried this:

```
$ yes > yeslog
```

So data is being written to `yeslog` continuously.

After I while I check the sizes with `ls -alh yeslog` and `du -h yeslog` and they report the same size.

Then I do `truncate -s 0K yeslog`, then I check the sizes again with `ls` and `du`. But now, `du` is showing a reduced size, while `ls` is showing the same size as before.

Why is this happening and is truncate really doing its job?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a variant of [How does linux manage the offsets of files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/619186/86440). Both `ls` and `du` are correct, they are measuring different things.

When you run `truncate`, it reduces the file to 0 bytes. However `yes` immediately writes to it again, at the offset following where it had written before; all the missing data is replaced with zeroes, and entirely missing blocks are replaced sparsely. As a result, the apparent size of the file keeps increasing, but the actual disk space it consumes on disk goes back to 0 every time you run `truncate`, and while it increases again when `yes` writes to it, the sparse blocks aren’t counted.

`ls` shows the apparent size of the file by default, whereas `du` shows the disk space consumed, so `ls` will show a larger value than `du` after the first `truncate` which loses an entire block. You can get `ls` to show the allocated size with the `-s` flag.

If you ask the shell to *append* to `yeslog` (`yes >> yeslog`), then the file will be opened with `O_APPEND` and `yes` will write from the beginning of the file after it’s truncated, instead of continuing to write at the same offset as before.

Comment: So if stop `yes`, will the missing data which are replaced with zeroes ever be written to disk? I mean, will a large apparent file size ever cause the actual file size on the disk to be large again?

Comment: No, the data is gone. However another program could write to the file, over the zeroes (if you ask it to) and cause the allocated file size to increase with increasing the apparent size.